# Exams with Beamer

Tags: beamer, exam

I want to create a document that can be three things:

1. a slideshow presentation,
2. a handout of the presentation with questions followed by enough space that students can write their own answers, and
3. a handout with typed solutions instead of space to handwrite solutions.

The beamer class accomplishes the first and the exam class accomplishes the second two, but because they are both classes I can't just switch back and forth between the two without creating a lot of errors due to undefined commands. I have explored many other packages that do things similar to the exam class, but none of them does everything that I am looking for. Does anyone know how I can get the functionality of both classes at once?

Edit: To clarify, I want to embed questions within frames.

```
\begin{frame}
    \begin{questions}
        \question Is this a test?
        \begin{solution}[3cm]
            Yes, this is a test.
        \end{solution}
    \end{questions}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: create a new class ;) welcome to TeX.SE, just show us what you have tried so far. Them explain what you need as a combined functionality. Without that it's just an unclear question.

Comment: What exactly should the question and solution do? Maybe one could reimplement something similar with beamer.

Comment: I want to create two versions of the handout. One version gets printed out with space for students to write in answers (instead of the solution). A second version contains the solutions (instead of space to write in answers) and is made available online.

Answer (score 5):

You can combine beamer and exam classes by using the `beamerarticle` package:

```
% For the presentation
\documentclass[ignorenonframetext]{beamer}

% for the questions and answers
%\documentclass{exam}
%\usepackage[notheorems]{beamerarticle}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
\question[10]
Why is there air?
\question[15]
How much wood would a woodchuck chuck if a woodchuck could chuck
wood?
\question[10] Compute $\displaystyle\int_0^1 x^2 \, dx$.
\end{questions}

\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Another approach: recreate the environments you need in beamer

```
\documentclass[notheorems]{beamer}

\newenvironment{questions}{}{}
\newcommand{\question}{}

% For the solution file
%\newenvironment{solution}{}{}

%For printing the student version
\newenvironment{solution}{\color{white}}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{questions}
  \question Is this a test?
  \begin{solution}
      Yes, this is a test.
  \end{solution}
\end{questions}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on SamCarter's answer. You can create a \newcommand to translate easily from beamer to exam and vice versa.

[image]
[image]

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage[notheorems]{beamerarticle}

%\documentclass{beamer}
%\newcounter{points}
%\newenvironment{choices}{\begin{enumerate}}{\end{enumerate}}
%\newenvironment{questions}{\setcounter{points}{0}}{}
%\newcommand{\question}[1][1]{\addtocounter{points}{#1}}


\newcommand{\hackQuestion}[5]{
  \mode<article>{
  \question #1
    \begin{parts}
      \part #2  
      \part #3
      \part #4
      \part #5
    \end{parts}  

  }
  \mode<beamer>{
  \begin{frame}{#1}
    \begin{choices}
      \item {#2}
      \item {#3}
      \item {#4}
      \item {#5}
    \end{choices}
  \end{frame}
  }
}



\begin{document}

\begin{questions}  
  \hackQuestion
  {This is my question}
  {answer 1}
  {answer 2}
  {answer 3}
  {answer 4}
\end{questions}


\end{document}
```